# Transpose and Copy to another sheet using Apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to transpose column data to rows based on the merged header using Apps Script.
Below is the view what would be my input and the expected output,

#### Input

[image]

#### Output

[image]

[Sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_EvxCwGlu-2wTyX_jo57k-DypD_VDLB8KLJA3FOixJ4/edit?usp=sharing)

#### What I've written so far:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("A1:AO1");
  
  var mergedValues = [];
  
  //get the header added to the array
  mergedValues.push(sheet.getRange("A2:I2").getValues());
  Logger.log(mergedValues);

  var mergedRanges = range.getMergedRanges();
  for (var i = 0; i < mergedRanges.length; i++) {
    var calcA1Notation = "A"+(i+3) + ":C"+(i+3);
    var monA1Notation = "D"+(i+3) + ":F"+(i+3);
    
    //Load the Transpose values into the array
    mergedValues.push([[
      sheet.getRange(calcA1Notation).getValues().toString(),
      mergedRanges[i].getDisplayValue(),
      sheet.getRange(monA1Notation).getValues().toString()
    ]]);
  }
  Logger.log(mergedValues[0].length);

  for (var i = 0; i < mergedValues.length; i++){
    //Writes to the lastrow+1 of the sheet
    sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow()+1, 1).setValue(mergedValues[i]);
  }
}
```

Can you guys help me in modifying google script to generate the expected result?

Comment: Please detail what is currently not working in your current code. Errors, logic failure, incorrect behavior, etc.

Comment: @tehhowch I'm not able to write the expected output on to the Google sheet. When I view the value of Array through Logger.Log(mergedValues) method I could see it has done the required transpose action but when I call a setValues(Object) method it doesn't write the expected result. Output as seen in the Logs,
[18-10-15 13:18:41:191 AEDT] [[Header 1, Header 2, Header 3, Header 6, Header 7, Header 8, Header 6, Header 7, Header 8]]
[18-10-15 13:18:41:192 AEDT] [[Data1,Data2,Data3, JUNE, Data6,Data7,Data8]]
[18-10-15 13:18:41:193 AEDT] [[Data2,Data3,Data4, JULY, Data7,Data8,Data9]]

Comment: @tehhowch I'm more happy if you're able to suggest a solution to resolve the problem rather than helping me with the actual code. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The question includes the term "Transpose", but this is misleading.
The goal of the questioner is straight-forward; to copy cells from one sheet to another. With one proviso, to include a column header from one sheet as a cell in the target range.

The questioner demonstrated code though they did not explain to what extent this was purposeful. The code takes three columns of data and concatenates the values into a single cell. At best, one might regard this as an early draft.

The referencing of the source data is uncomplicated; getting the month name is the main complication. I used two loops to work through the rows on the Source sheet because the questioner's intended outcome was that the data should sort by month.

I could have built a routine to convert the month string value to a numeric value, then sorted on that value (I certainly thought about it) - but I didn't;)

The Month names are in UPPERCASE, the questioner's outcome uses TitleCase. Again, I could have built a routine to convert the case, and I did spend some time trying. But in the end I decided that it was not a high priority.

```
function so5273586002() {

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

    // Declare the two sheets
    var sourcesheet = ss.getSheetByName("Input");
    var targetsheet = ss.getSheetByName("Output");

    // Get the respective starting row and ending rows.'' the target last row is declared in the loop.  
    var sourcestartrow = 3;
    var targetstartrow = 2;
    var sourcelastrow = sourcesheet.getLastRow();


    // get the the data
    var sourcerange = sourcesheet.getDataRange();
    var sourcevalues = sourcerange.getValues();


    // rubric for copying data.
    // each row of the source must create two rows in the target - one row for each month
    // the first three columns are repeats on both rows
    // each row includes the source data as well as the month name

    // target row #1
    // source columns A, B & C to target A,B,C
    // Month#1; value in D1 Source=> Target Column D (4)
    // source columns DEF to target E F G
    // target row #2
    // source columns A, B & C to target A,B,C
    // Month#2: value in G1 Source=> Target D (4)
    // source fields G, H I  to target E F G

    // the questioner's prefered layout is that all the rows are sorted by month; to achive this, I used two loops
    // the first to do the first month; the second to do the second month
    for (i = sourcestartrow; i < (sourcelastrow + 1); i++) {

        // get the last row for the target 
        var targetlastrow = targetsheet.getLastRow();

        // Columns A, B and C -> Columns A, B and C
        var targetRange = targetsheet.getRange(targetlastrow + 1, 1); //target: column =A, row = lastrow plus one
        var sourcetest = sourcesheet.getRange(i, 1, 1, 3).copyTo(targetRange); // range = active row, column=A, 1 row, 3 columns, copy to SheetTracker
        //Logger.log("source range is "+sourcesheet.getRange(i, 1, 1, 3).getA1Notation()+", target range is "+targetsheet.getRange(targetlastrow + 1, 1).getA1Notation());//DEBUG

        // Month Name from the header
        var targetRange = targetsheet.getRange(targetlastrow + 1, 4); //target: column =D, (month) row = lastrow plus one
        var sourcetest = sourcesheet.getRange(1, 4).copyTo(targetRange, {
            contentsOnly: true
        }); // range = active row, column=A, 1 row, 3 columns, copy to SheetTracker
        // Logger.log("source range is "+sourcesheet.getRange(1, 4).getA1Notation()+", target range is "+targetsheet.getRange(targetlastrow + 1, 4).getA1Notation());//DEBUG

        // Month details
        // Columns D E and F -> Columns E F and G
        var targetRange = targetsheet.getRange(targetlastrow + 1, 5); //target: column =E, row = lastrow plus one
        var sourcetest = sourcesheet.getRange(i, 4, 1, 3).copyTo(targetRange, {
            contentsOnly: true
        }); // range = active row, column=D(4), 1 row, 3 columns, copy to SheetTracker
        // Logger.log("source range is "+sourcesheet.getRange(i, 4, 1, 3).getA1Notation()+", target range is "+targetsheet.getRange(targetlastrow + 1, 5).getA1Notation());//DEBUG

    } // end loop#1


    //Loop#2 to generate rows for the second month
    for (i = sourcestartrow; i < (sourcelastrow + 1); i++) {

        // get the last row for the target 
        var targetlastrow = targetsheet.getLastRow();

        // Columns A, B and C -> Columns A, B and C
        var targetRange = targetsheet.getRange(targetlastrow + 1, 1); //target: column =A, row = lastrow plus one
        var sourcetest = sourcesheet.getRange(i, 1, 1, 3).copyTo(targetRange); // range = active row, column=A, 1 row, 3 columns, copy to SheetTracker
        //Logger.log("source range is "+sourcesheet.getRange(i, 1, 1, 3).getA1Notation()+", target range is "+targetsheet.getRange(targetlastrow + 1, 1).getA1Notation());//DEBUG

        // Month Name from the header
        var targetRange = targetsheet.getRange(targetlastrow + 1, 4); //target: column =D, (month) row = lastrow plus one
        var sourcetest = sourcesheet.getRange(1, 7).copyTo(targetRange, {
            contentsOnly: true
        }); // range = active row, column=G, 1 row, 3 columns, copy to SheetTracker
        //Logger.log("source range is "+sourcesheet.getRange(1, 7).getA1Notation()+", target range is "+targetsheet.getRange(targetlastrow + 1, 4).getA1Notation());//DEBUG

        // Month details
        // Columns G H and I -> Columns E F and G
        var targetRange = targetsheet.getRange(targetlastrow + 1, 5); //target: column =E, row = lastrow plus one
        var sourcetest = sourcesheet.getRange(i, 7, 1, 3).copyTo(targetRange, {
            contentsOnly: true
        }); // range = active row, column=D(4), 1 row, 3 columns, copy to SheetTracker
        // Logger.log("source range is "+sourcesheet.getRange(i, 7, 1, 3).getA1Notation()+", target range is "+targetsheet.getRange(targetlastrow + 1, 5).getA1Notation());//DEBUG
    } // end loop#2

}
```

---

This screenshot shows the Source sheet ("Input").
[image: Source sheet]

---

These screenshots show the Target sheet ("Output") before and after running the code.
[image: Target sheet - Before]

[image: Target sheet - After]

---

### UPDATE

As noted in my comments, the earlier draft lacked two things:
1) it was inefficient and followed poor practices because it wrote the value of each field as it was created. The more appropriate approach would have been to write the data to an array, and then copy the array to the target range when the row-by-row processing was complete.
2) the code consisted of two loops to cater for the 2 months in the demonstration data. However, this is an impractical outcome since it is probable that there will be, in reality, any number of months' data in each row. Again, poor practice, when a more appropriate approach was to assume any number of month's data. The more efficient approach would have been to build an array of data while looping through each row.

This revision overcomes both drawbacks.
In addition, since month names do not sort in any meaningful sequence, I added a numeric month id that can be used for filtering and sorting in the output data sheet.

```
function so5273586003() {

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

    // Declare the two sheets
    var sourcesheet = ss.getSheetByName("Input");
    var targetsheet = ss.getSheetByName("Output");

    // Get the respective starting row and ending rows.'' the target last row is declared in the loop.  
    var targetstartrow = 2;
    var sourcestartrow = 2;
    var sourcelastrow = sourcesheet.getLastRow();
    var sourcelastcolumn = sourcesheet.getLastColumn();
    //Logger.log("the last row is "+sourcelastow+", and the last column is "+sourcelastcolumn);

    // get the the data
    var sourcerange = sourcesheet.getDataRange();
    var sourcevalues = sourcerange.getValues();
    var sourcelength = sourcevalues.length;

    var i = 0;
    var m = 0;
    var month = 1;
    var dataarray = [];
    var masterarray = [];

    // start loop by row
    for (i = sourcestartrow; i < (sourcelastrow); i++) {


        // start loop by month (within row)
        for (m = 0; m <= (sourcelastcolumn - 6); m = m + 3) {

            dataarray = [];

            // add first three columns
            dataarray.push(sourcevalues[i][0]);
            dataarray.push(sourcevalues[i][1]);
            dataarray.push(sourcevalues[i][2]);

            //add the month name
            dataarray.push(sourcevalues[0][3 + m]);

            //add month data
            dataarray.push(sourcevalues[i][3 + m]);
            dataarray.push(sourcevalues[i][4 + m]);
            dataarray.push(sourcevalues[i][5 + m]);

            //create month id
            switch (sourcevalues[0][3 + m]) {
                case "JULY":
                    month = 1;
                    break;
                case "AUGUST":
                    month = 2;
                    break;
                case "SEPTEMBER":
                    month = 3;
                    break;
                case "OCTOBER":
                    month = 4;
                    break;
                case "NOVEMBER":
                    month = 5;
                    break;
                case "DECEMBER":
                    month = 6;
                    break;
                case "JANUARY":
                    month = 7;
                    break;
                case "FEBRUARY":
                    month = 8;
                    break;
                case "MARCH":
                    month = 9;
                    break;
                case "APRIL":
                    month = 10;
                    break;
                case "MAY":
                    month = 11;
                    break;
                case "JUNE":
                    month = 12;
                    break;
                default:
                    month = 100;
                    break;

            } // end switch

            // add the month id to the array (used for sorting)
            dataarray.push(month);

            // add the data to the master array before zeroing for next month
            masterarray.push(dataarray);

        } // months loop

    } // end row loop

    // get the length of the master array
    var masterlength = masterarray.length;
    // define the target range
    var TargetRange = targetsheet.getRange(targetstartrow, 1, masterlength, 8);
    // set the array values on the Target sheet
    TargetRange.setValues(masterarray);

}
```

Comment: The apps-script provided helps me in solving the problem for 2 months, what if I've to extend it for some more months? Would you recommend to create multiple loops for each month?

Comment: @SathishRkrish More loops is the option for the code as it stands. I;m assuming that you've got 12 months (or more woith of data?? Just remind me - is this is one-off event, or something to be done once in a while? The reason for the loops is the sorting by month in the output sheet. It would make more sense to do it row by row, and then manually sort later. By the same token, you could probably add the loops and have the job finished by the time the code was re-written to do it differently. Really up to you.

Comment: It's going to be a regular job week on week and I'll try to modify the code accordingly. Also, will parse it row by row and if I'm stuck in between, I'll seek help here. Cheers

Comment: @SathishRkrishIf You're happy with this answer, please click the "Accept" button.

Comment: @SathishRkrish Refer my Update. I felt that I had not used sound coding practices, so I have updated the code to cater for any number of columns. I also added an extra column to the Output so enable sorting by month.